# How to generate complete AST from GraphQL input object

Tags: graphql, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm playing around with the [visit](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/language/#visit) and [TypeInfo](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#typeinfo) utilities to analyse some graphql queries. I want to analyse and, eventually, modify a filter specified as a [graphcool style input filter](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/graphql-api/query-api-nia9nushae#filtering-by-field)

However, I'm not able to retrieve the information I'd expect. Given this query:

```
{
    Systems (filter: { code_in: ["lemon"] }) {
        code
    }
}
```

with this code:

```js
    visit(parse(systemFilter), {
        enter: node => {
            typeInfo.enter(node);
            console.log(JSON.stringify( typeInfo.getFieldDef(), null, 2))
            console.log(JSON.stringify( typeInfo.getArgument(), null, 2))
        },
        leave: node => {
            typeInfo.leave(node);
        },
    });
```

I don't find any references to `code_in` or `lemon` in the logs.

Are properties of input objects less available to graphql AST tooling, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug/undocumented limitation in the TypeInfo utility. If I log out the raw node and grep for 'lemon' I find what I'm after.